# Parse structured string data from Firewall Syslog Entires into dict with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

I have a structured string fed in via a socket to my Python script which is able to receive UDP syslog data from another item on my network.  This string is in the format of this:

```
<30>device="SFW" date=2019-03-07 time=11:12:19 timezone="EST" device_name="SFV4C6" device_id=C12345678ABCXYZ log_id=063110617710 log_type="Event" log_component="SSL VPN Authentication" log_subtype="Authentication" status="Successful" priority=Information user_name="valid@username" usergroupname="" auth_client="N/A" auth_mechanism="AD" reason="" src_ip=123.234.123.234 message="User valid@username authenticated successfully to login to SSLVPN through AD authentication mechanism" name="" src_mac=
<30>device="SFW" date=2019-03-07 time=11:12:20 timezone="EST" device_name="SFV4C6" device_id=C12345678ABCXYZ log_id=062910617701 log_type="Event" log_component="Firewall Authentication" log_subtype="Authentication" status="Successful" priority=Information user_name="valid@username" usergroupname="vpnallaccess" auth_client="SSLVPN" auth_mechanism="" reason="" src_ip=10.1.250.123 message="User valid@username of group vpnallaccess logged in successfully to Firewall through  authentication mechanism from 10.1.250.3" name="User Name" src_mac=
```

... with numerous key-value pairs in the string. (Note that `key= otherkey=something` is valid where `key=` is empty and would be interpreted as `key=None`, apparently, with this firewall's syslog implementation)

I for the life of me have not figured out how to properly split this out to get the key-value pairs into a dict file in Python.  Simply splitting on spaces won't work because some of the double-quoted strings contain spaces.

Does anyone have a nifty way to split out the data and parse it into a dict object so I can directly reference log values in it rather than having to constantly split out specific data from the string each time with long regex, etc.?

Comment: NOTE: I do not control the strings; these strings're generated by a firewall appliance and handed off to the simple UDP listener syslog server that I have.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Actually those *are* the full strings now.  They end with a simple EndOfLine.  Each line is processed independently from each other as each line is a separate item from the appliance handed to syslog independently.  Would the code I use for the syslog implementation be useful to see here?

Comment: Ah ok, and individual key-value pairs can just end with `=` i.e. with no value?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Correct; an empty value will just have `key=` and would be interpreted as `key=None`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`shlex`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#module-shlex) does the job for you:

```
import shlex

s = '<30>device="SFW" date=2019-03-07 time=10:59:05 timezone="EST" device_name="SF4C6" log_component="SSL VPN Authentication"'

print({x: y for x, y in map(lambda x: x.split('='), shlex.split(s))})
# {'<30>device': 'SFW', 'date': '2019-03-07', 'time': '10:59:05', 'timezone': 'EST', 'device_name': 'SF4C6', 'log_component': 'SSL VPN Authentication'}
```

Comment: This is some kind of ***unholy black magic*** you have found/used!  But it works EXACTLY how I need it to!  Thank you kindly!  I like the use of `lambda` here to further handle the mapping of the key-value pairs as well, nice going!  (I rarely use lambda functions but I keep forgetting how useful they can be!)